# I have problem with hebrew in Mysql. I use with visualstudio10, connector and linq. what can i do?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

the query works well only in english.
*the tables and all DB is utf-8(utf-8_general_ci)
I see hebrew in the db(phpmyadmin or mysql Workbench)
the problem is to read VALUES from the db.

*I use linqtosql to do the query and the model is EntityFramework.

this is a sample:

```
        using (dbEntities model = new dbEntities())
        {            

            List<string> lstNoth = new List<string>();                
            var query = from t in model.producttype                           
                        where t.ProductTypeName.Contains(text)
                        select new
                        {                                
                           t.ProductTypeName
                        };

            foreach (var item in query) //value in hebrew didn't get inside.
            {
                lstNoth.Add(item.ProductTypeName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: *same query in db of microsoft(mssql or .mdf) works well with hebrew and english.

Comment: Does it get inside if you remove the `where` clause?

Comment: did you try to enable query log on the server side and look  into what SQL string your Linq is transformed?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. I add the sentence- charset=utf8 to the connectionString in WebConfig.

```
database=XXXX;charset=utf8
```

The problem solved. Thanks anyway for your help.